# Conga Nested tables and queries

Tags: reporting, conga

I would like to use Conga to generate proposals from a quote.  I've read that Conga supports nested tables.

On Quote I have an Quote Line Item grouping object.  This object has a self reference and go two levels deep.

The QLIs can be related to any grouping object.

I would like Conga to list all the QLIs through all the grouping objects but I'm not sure if Conga queries are powerful enough to support this.

Anybody have enough experience with Conga to know this?

Answer (score 2):

In Composer Release 8, detail regions can be nested inside one another if the detail data is retrieved through a nested SOQL query.

Note - Building nested queries is not supported by Conga Support. This functionality is supported in Microsoft Word templates only.

You can check out this url for further reference - 
https://support.conga.com/content/composer/creating-composer-templates/word-templates/advanced-word-templates/nested-soql-queries

In order to accompanish your job you can create custom apex classes and vf pages.

Answer (score 1):

As I recall, I ran into a similar issue in early 2014 with nested tables. My queries were based on the contact, a custom child object, and a custom grand-child object. At the time, nesting was limited to 1 level, and after speaking with support, they indicated that this was likely to remain the case.

The solution I ended up going with was to use apex to create a text field that 'rolled up' all of the child objects to the 2nd-level record, displaying one per line. Eventually we replaced this page with a Visualforce page rendered as a pdf and have been much happier.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I'm going to try my luck with a lot conditional logic and see where that leads me.

Comment: No problem. Please upvote this answer if it was useful, and let me know if I can be of more assistance.